# Pages in beamer are incorrectly numbered when using "show notes on second screen"

Tags: beamer, page-numbering

I'm using `beamer` to create a presentation, and want to use the mode "show notes on second screen". Unfortunately, there seems to be a bug: when I turn it on, the page numbers are shifted one page up, so page 1 becomes 2, 2 becomes 3, and so on, with the last page number being repeated. With overlays, the numbers also shits one position, so the previous page of the overlay, and the last one has incorrect number.

I attach a minimum sample file: just check the PDF page numbers. By commenting the line `\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=left}`, the numbers work fine; when adding it, the numbering fails.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{pgfpages}

\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=left}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
First frame (should be 1)
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Second frame (should be 2)
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Third frame (should be 3)\\

\pause
Also third frame (should also be 3)
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Fourth frame (should be 4)
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi i don´t understand your Problem. Frame number one has logical number 1 aso. For paused frames several pages are produced which (of course) have different pdf page numbers (they are different pages).

Comment: @bloodworks: well, if you compile that code, frame one will be numbered 2 in the PDF, which is part of the problem. And actually frames with `\pause` in Beamer generate PDF pages with the same page number, even if they are different pages.

Comment: @Sergio Costas: the problem seems to be `pgfpages`. At least the `pgf` manual refers the issue (page 515): "Another word of caution: using pgfpages will produce wrong page numbers in the .aux file.". Unfortunately, the fix they suggest doesn't work with your example.

Comment: @njsg i can´t confirm that sorry. When i run the above code i get properly numbered pdf pages. (pdflatex TL2011 and Preview (Mac OSX).) Except for that i wonder why this could be so important. Framenumbering will be all right anyway.

Comment: Question [71206](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71206/31931) "What is going on with pgfpages and page labels?" is a duplicate of this question. I, however, found that question first and [answered it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118299/31931). Should I replicate my answer here or is this comment sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I just ran into this problem myself and decided to do something about it.  I wrote a little perl script to shift the page numbers up one and add a number 1 for page 1.  This reverses the mangling done by pgfpages, at least for me.

You'll need to have perl installed and the CAM::PDF module from CPAN.

[Download the program](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7s3eaKw_zFeai1hNHVkTHJJSGc/edit?usp=sharing)