# Incorrect PDF page numbering in beamer with notes on same page

Tags: beamer, pdftex, page-numbering

I have created a beamer presentation and I want to show the notes on the same page using the beamer option `show notes on second screen=right`. With this option disabled, the page numbers in the produced PDF match the frame numbers on each frame. However, when I enable this option, the page numbers in the produced PDF document are wildly incorrect, no longer matching the frame numbers. I would like this numbering to match as it makes it easier to jump between slides if I so desire.

(Note that I am not talking about the absolute page number, which always increments, but the page number that can be set manually in a PDF. In the screenshot below, taken in Adobe Acrobat, I am talking about the page number 5, not 10.)

[image: Page number in Adobe Acrobat. It shows a page number 5, and then 10 of 19 in parentheses.]

I have created an MWE to show the problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Page number should be \insertframenumber
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Page number should be \insertframenumber
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Page number should be \insertframenumber
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Page number should be \insertframenumber
        \item<2-> Some extra items
        \item<3-> To see whether weird things happen
        \item<3-> When I add overlay specifications in a frame
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Page number should be \insertframenumber
        \item<2-> Some extra items
        \item<3-> To see whether weird things happen
        \item<4-> When I add overlay specifications
        \item<5-> In a frame
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Page number should be \insertframenumber
        \item From this point on, the page numbers even start reversing
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Page number should be \insertframenumber
        \item<2-> But it only gets weirder
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Page number should be \insertframenumber
        \item<2-> But it keeps jumping to 6
        \item<3-> and back
        \item<4-> and back to 6
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The MWE does not load any packages other than the beamer class, and it configures the notes to be shown on the second screen. The rest of the code is simply creating some frames, sometimes with overlay specifications (it can most likely be shortened, but I could not find out what exactly produces the issue).

I have already tried implementing an (in my opinion, hacky) fix by using the `BeforeBeginEnvironment` command from `etoolbox` as follows:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{\renewcommand{\thepage}{\insertframenumber}}
```

While this does have an effect on the page numbering generated in the PDF, it is still incorrect. Other `etoolbox` commands, such as `AtBeginEnvironment`, `AtEndEnvironment`, and `AfterEndEnvironment` didn't seem to have any effect. Using `\setcounter{page}{\insertframenumber}` within the `{Before/After/At}{Begin/End}Environment` command also leads to incorrect results.

Below, I have summarised the PDF page numbers generated on my system using various methods and the MWE given above. All PDF documents were generated with `pdflatex`. I have numbered the methods to keep the table readable.

1. No notes (correct numbering)
2. Notes, no additional commands
3. Notes, `BeforeBeginEnvironment` to renew `\thepage`
4. Notes, `BeforeBeginEnvironment` to set the `page` counter

| Absolute page number | Method 1 | Method 2 | Method 3 | Method 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 6 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 7 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 8 | 6 | 4 | 4 | 3 |
| 9 | 6 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 10 | 6 | 5 | 5 | 4 |
| 11 | 6 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 12 | 6 | 6 | 5 | 5 |
| 13 | 7 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 14 | 8 | 7 | 5 | 6 |
| 15 | 8 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 16 | 9 | 8 | 6 | 5 |
| 17 | 9 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 18 | 9 | 9 | 6 | 6 |
| 19 | 9 | 6 | 6 | 6 |

What is the cause of this issue and how can I fix this, so that I can both use notes and get the correct numbering?

Edit: I have done some more research into this behaviour, and I found that it is actually caused by the `pdfpages` package, which is used by `beamer` to insert the notes page next to the frame. The `pgfpages` documentation also warns for this:

> Another word of caution: *using `pgfpages` will produce wrong page numbers in the `.aux` file.*

A similar question [has been asked a number of years ago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71206/what-is-going-on-with-pgfpages-and-page-labels), and while it does have an answer, sadly I cannot get a compiled PDF when I include the code provided in that answer in my MWE. Instead, `pdflatex` seems to enter an infinite loop, constantly producing new pages. A comment on this answer confirms this behaviour. Furthermore, while I might be able to understand what's going on in the answer to that question, I would have no idea how to debug the encountered problem, let alone fix it.

Comment: I, too have been having a lot of issues with `pgfpages` and (virtual) page numbers (and footnotes, but that's a different story). About the only thing that worked for me was using `\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}`. That way, slide (not: page) numbers are used throughout. I realize this is not ideal.